# Label backcolor not going transparent

Tags: c#, winforms, label, transparency, backcolor

I've set a label's BackColor property to 'Transparent' in windows form but its just White? It's not going transparent?

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Are you expecting that setting it transparent would have a see through effect ? well then that is not the case

Comment: someone else, I suppose, is set it to white.

Comment: you want to hide lable or want to change colour of label?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The label does not support transparency, you must create your own unique custom control, you can see these code examples.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/transparent_controls_net.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/uLabelX.aspx