# Making the text of a label transparent in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency, picturebox

I have a label with a black BackColor and I have set the ForeColor to Transparent. The label is over a mostly blue PictureBox which I have set as its parent. 
For some reason, the text, which should show blue, is white. 
It doesn't seem to have any relation to the form color or the color of the picture box.
Also when I make the labels BackColor transparent it works fine.
Thanks

Comment: "Also when I make the labels BackColor transparent it works fine". If it works fine, then do that, surely?

Comment: @DavidArno They mean transparent background works fine, but they want transparent foreground.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to have to custom-draw the foreground on this one.

Comment: Try setting the transparency map on your form to an unused color, then setting label text that color? Totally untested, just a thought.

Comment: Looks like winforms doesn't really support transparency see here for some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622052/label-backcolor-not-going-transparent.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a "feature" of the Label class. If transparency was allowed, it would show the text in the Labels background colour (transparent or not) and your text would by definition be invisible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've tried customizing a `Label` supporting Transparent ForeColor but I've done it **partially** successfully. It **does** work great for many BackColors but it also **doesn't work** as expected for fairly many other BackColors. However using it with some working BackColor is acceptable if you like the BackColor. This code has to deal with `Image`, first we have to draw string on an `Image` (using high quality drawing), then we have to convert all the Text (which should be drawn with `Color.Black`) to the `Color.Transparent`. We also have to take all the colors between the `Color.Black` and the `BackColor`) into account, these **medium** colors (centralized mainly on the text curves) make the most trouble thing to solve. That's why there are some BackColors making it work unexpectedly. It can be solved if we have some better algorithm to scan through all the possible **medium** colors and convert them to the corresponding transparent colors (with alpha being less than 255). To convert from source color to destination color, we use many `ColorMaps` together with an `ImageAttribute`, this attribute will be used to determine how to draw the Image. In fact we can read each source pixel and draw the corresponding destination pixel but doing so requires more code (it's worth trying that way). Here is the complete code for the `CustomLabel`:

```
public class CustomLabel : Label {
    public CustomLabel() {
        BackColor = base.BackColor;
        base.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        DoubleBuffered = true;                     
    }
    Color backColor;
    int alpha;
    public new Color BackColor {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(alpha, backColor); }
        set { 
           alpha = value.A;
           backColor = Color.FromArgb(value.R, value.G, value.B);
           UpdateVisual(true);               
        }
    }        
    protected override void OnForeColorChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnForeColorChanged(e);
        if (ForeColor == Color.Transparent) {
            base.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            UpdateVisual(true);
        } else {
            base.BackColor = BackColor;
            BackgroundImage = null;
        }
    }
    Image img;        
    private void UpdateVisual(bool applyChange) {     
        img = new Bitmap(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img)){
            g.Clear(backColor);             
            g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;                
            g.DrawString(Text, Font, Brushes.Black, ClientRectangle);
        }
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm)) {
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
            ImageAttributes ia = new ImageAttributes();
            List<ColorMap> cms = new List<ColorMap>();                
            for (decimal f = 0; f < 1; f += 0.001M) {
                ColorMap cm = new ColorMap();
                cm.NewColor = Color.FromArgb((int)((1 - f) * alpha), backColor);
                cm.OldColor = GetNormalBlendColor(backColor,Color.Black, f);                    
                cms.Add(cm);
            }              
            ia.SetRemapTable(cms.ToArray());                                
            g.DrawImage(img, new Point[] {Point.Empty, new Point(img.Width, 0), new Point(0,img.Height) }, new Rectangle() {Size = bm.Size}, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);
        }
        img.Dispose();          
        img = bm;
        if (applyChange) BackgroundImage = img;
    }
    public Color GetNormalBlendColor(Color baseColor, Color blendColor, decimal opacity) {
        int R = Math.Min((int)((1 - opacity) * baseColor.R + blendColor.R * opacity), 255);
        int G = Math.Min((int)((1 - opacity) * baseColor.G + blendColor.G * opacity), 255);
        int B = Math.Min((int)((1 - opacity) * baseColor.B + blendColor.B * opacity), 255);                        
        return Color.FromArgb(R, G, B);
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        if (ForeColor != Color.Transparent) {
            using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(BackColor)) {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, ClientRectangle);
            }
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }                        
    }      
    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        if(ForeColor == Color.Transparent) UpdateVisual(true);
    }
    protected override void OnFontChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnFontChanged(e);
        if(ForeColor == Color.Transparent) UpdateVisual(true);
    }
    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        if (ForeColor == Color.Transparent) UpdateVisual(true);          
    }

}
```

[image]

PS: I hope someone will find a fix to complete this code, it works almost great but for some `BackColor`, the text curve becomes distinct and is like a randomly dotted curve. The worst back color to see that *bug* is `Color.Chocolate` :)

For some non-working BackColor :) here is for `Color.Chocolate`:

[image]

Comment: Your answers are getting hard to read, go easy on the backtick and the bold for an old guy like me, please.

Comment: @HansPassant sorry, I don't think it's hard to read, using backtick or bold even makes me type more (which is not what everyone wants), I just think it's more readable.

Comment: Most people are used to reading books and news papers, they just don't look like that in my neck of the world.  Do they in Vietnam?  I find it personally impossible to see the words between the ones yelling for attention.  It is certainly entirely up to you to do it the way you like, just giving a heads-up that you're losing a common reader (and voter) of your answers.

Comment: Could you maybe also add an image which shows how exactly is it "like a randomly dotted curve"?

Comment: @C.B. could you try it yourself? it's easy.

Comment: @C.B. also added snap shot for `non-working BackColor` as you want.